# wp_enqueue_style not working in Child Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I have this Child Theme and when I try to enqueue the styles and the javascript I run into an error:

- wp_enqueue_script is working fine
- wp_enqueue_style doesn't work at all

wp_head() is included in the header and it worked before, but after updating Avast theme and wordpress the problem started to occurre.

**functions.php**

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'); //not working
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancy', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css'); //not working
    wp_enqueue_script( 'devtools', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.min.js' ); //working

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [wordpress child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) documentation.

There you can find this line

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( 'parenthandle' ), 
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! 
Still funny that it worked without problems before the WP 5.7.2 update.